# Extracting points in a regular interval from TIN-Interpolation raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I had million of points with x, y and z. I could not filter them in QGIS in order to get them in an interval of every 0,9m. So what I did is TIN-Interpolation and I do have a raster now.

How can I get regular points from this raster in an interval of every 0,9 m? I need to extract points with an elevation value.

Comment: a height interval or a .9m grid?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I have a raster that i created with TIN-Interpolation tool. I need to get regular points in a 0,9 m grid from this raster and the points must have an elevation value. I tried 'regular points' tool, but it gave me points in a regular 0,9 m grid but without an elevation value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a [Point GRID](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid) with the extent of your raster and 0.9 m spacing
2. [Sample raster values](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling)